# failed to run boost mpi

Tags: c++, boost, mpi

After successfully build my c++ program using boost mpi library in a super computer resource. I failed to run my program:

```
login2.stampede(23)$ ./polytope 
LiMIC: (limic_open) file open fail
[unset]: aborting job:
Fatal error in MPI_Init:
Other MPI error, error stack:
MPIR_Init_thread(436)....: 
MPID_Init(371)...........: channel initialization failed
MPIDI_CH3_Init(335)......: 
MPIDI_CH3I_SMP_Init(1723): LiMIC2 device does not exist: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone has any hint on what is possibly happening? Thank you.

Comment: don't you run it a mpirun -np [processCount] ./polytope?